# Nginx-Ingress is not exposing Kubernetes Services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

So, I have Kubernetes installed on a private server with IP `192.168.9.150` (let's say it's `9.150`). And then I have a (long) single yaml file like this:

*(Make it simple, there's a deployment with 1 Express App (`billing-api`), 1 React App (`billing-web`) Redis (3 app in 1 pod) and another pod for curl. And then, there are some services that used for accessing external service, 2 ConfigMaps for `billing-api` and `billing-web` env, `billing-service` service with 80 (`billing-web`) and 1234 (`billing-api`) ports and Ingress Nginx Installed.)

[kubernetes.yaml](https://pastebin.com/pvpdh9c7)
*Sorry, cannot paste it here, marked as spam.

Then I run `kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml`, also I already have Ingress Nginx running with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

For testing that each pods can communicate, I run `kubectl exec -it pod/curl -- sh` and then run `curl billing-service:1234` and `curl billing-service` commands, and they return the right result from `billing-service` service.
I also have edited the `/etc/hosts` and add the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 billing.meetaza.dev
127.0.0.1 api.meetaza.dev
```

But, the problem is, when I try to curl from `9.150`, it says:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.meetaza.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

And

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to billing.meetaza.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

I thought that I miss a part of Kubernetes Deployment, but I have no idea about that (since I was following a tutorial in YT with Minikube installed instead of the real Kubernetes on a server).

I've trying to google it, but I was limited about what really happened here. Please tell me if there's an exact issue in StackOverflow.

This is my screenshot of `kubectl get all` and `kubectl get all --namespace ingress-nginx`:
[kubectl get all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TzRU.png)

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get ingress`. This should display the ingresses created in your default namespace.

Comment: @RrR- Sorry I currently doesn't have access there (offline), but I took this picture, may it could help. [kubectl describe ingress billing-ingress](http://prntscr.com/1rpsh0g)